# How this kotlin enum expression evaluates to true or false

Tags: kotlin, enums

I'm learning Kotlin from examples given in [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/03_special_classes/02_Enum) and trying to understand this containsRed function.

```
enum class Color(val rgb: Int) {                      // 1
    RED(0xFF0000),                                    // 2
    GREEN(0x00FF00),
    BLUE(0x0000FF),
    YELLOW(0xFFFF00);

    fun containsRed() = (this.rgb and 0xFF0000 != 0)  // 3
    }

fun main() {
    val red = Color.RED
    println(red)                                      // 4
    println(red.containsRed())                        // 5
    println(Color.BLUE.containsRed())                 // 6
}
```

My question is how

> (this.rgb and 0xFF0000 != 0)

gets evaluated to True for RED and False for others.

0xFF0000 != 0 will always get evaluated to true
this.rgb contains value which should get evaluated to true as well

Why does it get evaluated to false for GREEN, BLUE, and YELLOW?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`and` in the case of kotlin is a bitwise operator which we can write as

`(this.rgb and 0xFF0000 != 0)`

In the case of `RED` it will be `(0xFF0000 and 0xFF0000 != 0)` which resolves to `TRUE` but in any other case bitwise and operation will result in 0. for example in the case of GREEN it will be `(0x00FF00 and 0xFF0000)` all bits will be `0` and so it'll resolve to `0x000000` and `(0x000000 != 0)` is `false`